# How to append value from spring boot to a field in MongoDB (Java)?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I want to append a value to an existing field. I have a mongoDB collection, Person and that Person Document looks like below:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "64d4b688638bed43641ca2fb"
    },
    "email": "gvvg@gv",
    "contact": {
        "address": "vffv",
        "age": 22,
        "brand": null,
        "email": "gvvg@gv",
        "name": "Bruce"
    }
}
```

I want to run a query where "Wayne" gets appended to the field "name" so that the final data stored in mongo will be "Bruce Wayne".

I tried the below code but it is appending the array and not working.

```
update.set(
          "name",
          new Document("$concat",
          List.of(
          "name" +
          "wayne"
          )));
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a [pipelined update](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/).

```
db.collection.update(
    {},
    [
        {$set: 
            {"contact.name": {$concat: ["$contact.name"," Wayne"]}}
        }
    ]
);
```

In SpringBoot,

```
Query query = Query.query(<your filter criteria>);
AggregationUpdate update = Aggregation.newUpdate()
    .set("contact.name").toValue(
        StringOperators.Concat.valueOf("contact.name").concat(" Wayne")
    );

mongoTemplate.updateMulti(query, update, <your collection>.class);
```